# Mal funcionamiento datepicker en 2nda búsqueda - PHP JS

Tags: php, javascript, html, datepicker

Tengo un **buscador de reservas** mediante un rango de fechas, **check_in** y **check_out**.

```
<label for="check_in"><b>Entrada:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" name="check_in" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_in'])){ echo $_POST['check_in']; }?>">

<label for="check_out"><b>Salida:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida" name="check_out" id="check_out" onchange="calculoNoches();" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_out'])){ echo $_POST['check_out']; }?>" disabled>
```

Muestro las fechas en el campo `input` de tipo `text` mediante la clase **Datepicker**.
Implementando sus **librerías** necesarias como son las siguientes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**Explico el mal funcionamiento del Datepicker.**
De inicio, se muestra bloqueada `check_out` debido a que es necesario SIEMPRE un `check_in`, para poder tener un `check_out` posteriormente.

Insertamos un `check_in` (aparece seleccionado de un color azul el día actual), posteriormente se habilita `check_out`, entonces elegimos un `check_out`, aparecen disponibles las fechas posteriores al `check_in` seleccionado anteriormente.

**Pulsamos Buscar, y todo OK. Primera búsqueda... Bien.**

Ahora volvemos a realizar una segunda búsqueda para encontrar resultados diferentes, **aquí viene el error.**
Aparece deshabilitado, como siempre, `check_out`, hasta que elegimos un `check_in`. 
**¡¡¡Error a continuación!!!** Entonces cuando nos disponemos a seleccionar el `check_out`, encuentro que puedo elegir CUALQUIER fecha, hasta fechas de 2004 o 2012, aquí el error.

**Código:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Reservar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function() {
                var defaults = {
                    closeText: 'Cerrar', 
                    prevText: '<Anterior', 
                    nextText: 'Siguiente>', 
                    currentText: 'Hoy', 
                    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'], 
                    monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'], 
                    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'], 
                    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'], 
                    dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'], 
                    weekHeader: 'Sm', 
                    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd', 
                    firstDay: 1, 
                    isRTL: false, 
                    showMonthAfterYear: false, 
                    yearSuffix: '' 
                }; 

                $.datepicker.setDefaults(defaults); 

                $("#check_in").datepicker({
                    minDate: 0, //The value "0" means today (0 days from today). 
                    onSelect: function(dateStr) { 
                        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); //Día actual. 
                        if (minDate) { 
                            //Se comprueba si existe una fecha de salida.
                            var maxDate = $("#check_out").datepicker('getDate'); 
                            if (maxDate && minDate < maxDate) {} else { 
                                //Si existe una fecha de salida y es menor a la fecha de entrada.
                                minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1); 
                                //Se cambia la fecha al día siguiente del seleccionado en la fecha de entrada.
                                $('#check_out').datepicker('setDate', minDate). 
                                datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate); //Día siguiente al actual en "check_out". 
                            } 
                        } 
                        $('#check_out').change(); //Activar el evento "onchange". 
                        $('#check_out').prop("disabled", false); //Se activa la fecha de salida.
                    } 
                }); 

                $('#check_out').datepicker().on("input click", function(e) { 
                    console.log("Fecha salida cambiada: ", e.target.value); 
                }); 
            });
        </script> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="contenedor">
            <div class="busqueda">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="mibusqueda" id="mibusqueda" method="POST" class="form_buscar">
                    <h2>RESERVAR</h2>
                    <label for="check_in"><b>Entrada:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" name="check_in" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_in'])){ echo $_POST['check_in']; }?>">

                    <label for="check_out"><b>Salida:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida" name="check_out" id="check_out" onchange="calculoNoches();" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_out'])){ echo $_POST['check_out']; }?>" disabled>

                    <label for="personas"><b>Personas:</b></label>
                    <?php
                    echo "<select name='personas'>";
                        //Si la variable no existe, establecemos el valor por defecto.
                        if(!isset($_POST['personas'])){
                            $_POST['personas'] = 2;
                        }

                        for ($i=1; $i<11; $i++) {
                            if($i == $_POST['personas']){
                                echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
                            }else{
                                echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
                            }
                        }
                    echo "</select>";
                    ?>
                    <div align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar" id="buscar"><br/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="mostrar_cabanas">
                <?php
                //Aqui viene los datos cargados en la busqueda...
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Función calculoNoches:**

```
function calculoNoches(){
    var check_in = document.getElementById("check_in").value;
    var check_out = document.getElementById("check_out").value;
    var f1 = moment(check_in);
    var f2 = moment(check_out);
    var noches = f2.diff(f1, "days");
    //Comprobación del número de noches.
    if(noches <= 0){
        document.getElementById("calculoNoches").innerHTML = "";
    }else if(noches == 1){
        document.getElementById("calculoNoches").innerHTML = "Estancia de una noche.";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("calculoNoches").innerHTML = "Estancia de "+noches+" noches.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Me resulta imposible reproducir tu error, es posible que este venga de la función `calculoNoches()` cuya definición no has incluido en la pregunta, por lo que no es posible determinar si el error viene de ahí.

Comment: Ingreso la función calculoNoches() pero ahí no está el problema debido a que lo que falla es el Datepicker, no el calculoNoches(), y en la primera búsqueda si FUNCIONA TODO correctamente, donde falla es en la segunda búsqueda... ¿Cargará algo antes o después que no deba al actualizarse la página? No sé no sé...

Comment: @wallek876 Código añadido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que tienes el problema después de recargar la página, no me había dado cuenta de que el error se producía una vez recargada la página.

La causa está en que cada vez que se carga la página se reinicializan los selectores de fecha, y como esta vez ya tienen un valor, cuando eliges una fecha anterior a la seleccionada primero para el `check_in` no se establece la fecha mínima para `check_out` con lo que puedes seleccionar fechas anteriores.

Para solucionarlo simplemente tienes que establecer la fecha mínima cuando se produce este caso, simplemente añadiendo el código dentro de la condición que ya tienes.

```
  if (maxDate && minDate < maxDate) {

    minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
    $("#check_out").datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate);

  } else {

    minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
    $("#check_out").datepicker("setDate", minDate).datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate); 

  }
```

Comment: Mejor explicado y compartido imposible. Cuantas vuelvas me daba este error en la cabeza... ¡Mil gracias!.