# Tratamiento de un textarea - PHP

Tags: php, textarea

Si **envío una opinión sobre una reserva** y el **textarea** de opinión está vacío no debe permitir enviar la opinión.

El **problema** es que aunque esté vacío si acepta los espacios como una "**opinión**", debido a que no lo reconoce como vacío. (empty).

**Sólo se debe permitir enviar la opinión** si tiene un **mínimo de 5-10 carácteres** o al menos haya alguna letra escriba, sin contar espacios (debido a que los espacios los cuenta como texto).

Código:

```
echo "<textarea rows='4' cols='56' id='texto_opinion' name='texto_opinion'></textarea>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='add_opinion' id='add_opinion' value='Añadir opinión'>";

if(isset($_POST["add_opinion"])){
        if(isset($_POST['texto_opinion']) && !empty($_POST['texto_opinion'])){
            $idemail = $cliente;
            $idcabana = $_POST["a_anadir"];
            $opinion = $_POST["texto_opinion"];
            $fecha = new DateTime();
            $fecha_hoy = $fecha->format ('Y/m/d');
            $valoracion = isset($_POST["estrellas"])?$_POST["estrellas"]: "0"; //Sin marcar estrellas, valoracion=0.
            BD::insertarOpinionPorReserva($idemail, $idcabana, $opinion, $fecha_hoy, $valoracion);
        }else{
            echo '<script language="javascript">alert("¡Debes escribir una opinión!");</script>';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede que su problema a primera instancia se resuelva aplicando la función [trim()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php) , pero esta función eliminará solo los espacios al inicio y al final del texto.

Pero ¿Qué pasa si es que ingresan espacios entre dos letras? es decir `m           e` aplicando [trim()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php) retornaría más de 5 cuando solo hay dos letras. Para esto propongo reemplazar primero más de 1 espacio en blanco por solo 1 y luego realizar la validación, Esto se podría realizar por medio de la la función [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) empleando la expresión regular `\s+`

Otra recomendación quizá sería que no sea tan corto el rango de caracteres para la opinión de un cliente. *(para el ejemplo será entre 5 y 20)*

**Código**

```
if(isset($_POST["add_opinion"])){
    if(isset($_POST['texto_opinion'])){
        $entrada = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $_POST['texto_opinion']);
        if(strlen($entrada) >  4 && strlen($entrada) < 21){
            $valoracion = isset($_POST["estrellas"])? $_POST["estrellas"]: "0";
            echo "Gracias por Agregar su valoración :  " . $valoracion;
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Gracias por su Opinión ". $entrada;
        }
        else{
            echo "Debe agregar una Opinión Correcta para agregar la valoración  Min 5 - Max  20";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Totalmente correcto tu comentario @Dev. Joel

Comment: ¿Puedes hacerme un favor o encaminarme en una duda respecto a PHP?

Comment: @omaza1990 ¿ De qué se trata ? ¿ De la pregunta o mi respuesta ? Sí alguna duda en general quizá podría formular una nueva pregunta.Ya que hay que tener en cuenta que no se pueden utilizar los comentarios para conversaciones extendidas.

Comment: Se trata de otra pregunta, la tengo formulada en EO. Link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128673/mal-funcionamiento-datepicker-en-2nda-b%C3%BAsqueda-php-js

Answer (score 2):

Para solucionar tu problema debes almacenar la información en una variable y luego verificar que no este vacía, de la siguiente manera:

```
echo "<textarea rows='4' cols='56' id='texto_opinion' name='texto_opinion'></textarea>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='add_opinion' id='add_opinion' value='Añadir opinión'>";

if(isset($_POST["add_opinion"])){
    $texto_opcion = trim($_POST['texto_opinion']); /*Almacenas el textarea y le aplicas trim para que elimine los espacios vacios*/
        if($texto_opcion <> '' && strlen($texto_opcion) >= 5 && strlen($texto_opcion) <= 10){
            $idemail = $cliente;
            $idcabana = $_POST["a_anadir"];
            $opinion = $_POST["texto_opinion"];
            $fecha = new DateTime();
            $fecha_hoy = $fecha->format ('Y/m/d');
            $valoracion = isset($_POST["estrellas"])?$_POST["estrellas"]: "0"; //Sin marcar estrellas, valoracion=0.
            BD::insertarOpinionPorReserva($idemail, $idcabana, $opinion, $fecha_hoy, $valoracion);
        }else{
            echo '<script language="javascript">alert("¡Debes escribir una opinión!");</script>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Si quito los espacios con la función "trim()", ¿luego la opinión se envía con espacios o sin espacios? Es decir: hola que tal, se envia como "hola que tal " o como "holaquetal"?

Comment: @omaza1990  `trim()` solo elimina los espacios del principio y del final. Véase la documentación http://php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php

Comment: @omaza1990 como mencionaba Xerif la funcion `trim()` de `php` solo te elimina los espacios del comienzo y del final de tu cadena `string` esa función te ayuda a validar posteriormente que la variable no este vacía como es tu caso, no olvides marcar la repuesta con el **check de respuesta correcta** si soluciono tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Puede utilizar el atributo `required` o también `pattern` para especificar lo que permitido

Answer (score 0):

A ver creo que estas planteando de forma incorrecta tus requisitos:

> Sólo se debe permitir enviar la opinión si tiene un mínimo de 5-10 caracteres o al menos haya alguna letra escrita, sin contar espacios

Hay tienes ideas contradictorias, o tomas un mínimo de 5 caracteres o 1 carácter. Me quedaría con la de los 5, si bien la que requiere al menos un carácter es la más sencilla, si estás usando ***HTML5***, sólo tienes que añadir el atributo ***required***, el navegador hará automáticamente la validación:

```
<textarea
    rows='4'
    cols='56'
    id='texto_opinion'
    name='texto_opinion'
    required></textarea>
<input
    type='submit'
    name='add_opinion'
    id='add_opinion'
    value='Añadir opinión'>
```

Bien, no quieres que se envíe el *textarea* sin contenido, eso es parte cliente, la validación con PHP es una cosa aparte y se produciría una vez el formulario se envía y los datos llegan al servidor, si esta falla no puedes lanzar un *alert* sin más.
Para un contenido mínimo de x caracteres en el *textarea* requieres un poco de JS y algunos cambios:

1. Pulsar el "botón de enviar" no envía el formulario, lanzará las validaciones JS. Si las validaciones pasan, los datos se envían, en caso contrario, ahí es donde puedes usar el ***alert***.
2. Para validar el contenido del *textarea*, debes recuperarlo, por ejemplo usando la ID, y guardar el contenido en una variable.
3. Eliminar espacios en blanco sobrantes del contenido de la variable.
4. Contar los caracteres almacenados en la variable para comprobar que son al menos de la longitud esperada.

Answer (score 0):

Coloca **required** en la siguiente línea.

```
 echo "<textarea rows='4' cols='56' id='texto_opinion' name='texto_opinion' required></textarea>";
```

Comment: required no es del todo correcto con los espacios en blanco. Si en un campo text o textarea inserto muchos espacios en blanco, sin introducir ninguna letra, lo valida y el required desaparece.